# UDP chat server-client not able to communicate on diff machines

Tags: java, udp, sockets

I have written a UDP client server chat, I am able to communicate to server if both server and client are on same machine, but i am not able to do so when client is on some other machine using diff ip address. Is there any special setting to achieve this?

Regards,
Tara

Comment: Can you tell us how are you using the UDP? Maybe post your code snippet here.

Comment: my mode of operation is like server will multicast the incoming message to all the connected clients. while invoking the client, i have to pass the server address and port number of server as command line argument. 

Not sure about which code to post, thats why trying to explain the problem in detail !!

Comment: Maybe the specific code in the client that makes the connection to server and the server code where it is accepting connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping the other machine.

Disable firewall software on the other machine?

Make sure the other machine is listening on its actual IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: When I am invoking client from my own machine, I am able to communicate with server(Which is also on my machine) by using both localhost and the ip address. But on the other machine, I allow the firewall access for the client program and used the ip address of machine to try connecting to the server on my machine. The client is not givin any error but it is not able to communicate to server on my machine.

Comment: Have you check the firewall for port number also? Usually it has fine grained permission to the port number also. Check the client connection code again, it might be swallowing the exception. It can not be not giving any error, at the very least it would have given time out exception.

Comment: Yes, DJ gave good Idea, its the issue that after setting a port forwarding, I was able to make it work. I am marking sylvanaar's answer as accepted as it is actually firewall issue and then you need to set port forwarding if it is behind a network.